# Why would the purpose of <FilesMatch "\.(php|ini)$"> be?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been helping a friend with a wordpress website that mysteriously stopped allowing logins. After investigation, we discovered that the problem was the following section in a .htaccess file (that was in the folder above the WP root folder, but still a web accessible folder):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|ini)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My guess is that the host upgraded to Apache 2.4, which makes this syntax deprecated and caused the problem. I understand that changing it to

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|ini)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

would be correct, but I am not sure I understand why this section would be there in the first place, it seems like it would deny access to all files ending with .php or .ini, yet the site is a PHP based website, so won't this break everything? Do you know of any reasons such a file match might be used on a site? I wonder if it was supposed to be to prevent access to php.ini but whoever wrote it didn't understand the syntax and did a bad copy and paste.

Comment: Denying public access to any .ini files seems like a good idea, but I'm also not sure why you'd want to deny access to PHP files, other than making the site not public at all. What if you just remove the `PHP|` part? Also I don't know of any `htaccess` changes in Apache 2.4: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html

Comment: @edwardmp the order/deny stuff (i.e. mod_auth*) was reworked/removed in apache 2.4, so the old directives won't work anymore. Also is it possible all of your php files are named something like `.php5`?

Comment: @JonLin Thanks for the heads up, do I note that if you enable the module `mod_access_compat` the old htaccess syntax still works http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html

Comment: @edwardmp yeah I don't know why php would be in there either. It's easy to fix, I just am trying to work out why it was there to make sure I'm not breaking something that I am not aware of.

Comment: @JonLin the files are all .php - I think it was put there in error, just trying to understand if there is something that I might not be aware of. Thanks for the thought!